# ASUS: K55V series Laptop dual boot problem

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uefi, asus, grub-efi

I have LAPTOP ASUS K55V (Windows 7 Home 64bit)
(I'd like to dual boot with Ubuntu)

I read all the tutorials about install Ubuntu, here's what I did:

1. Installed old version 
   (problem: There some some Windows partitions and I can format some of them)
   (Backtrack 5R3 won't boot)
2. I download the latest Ubuntu. I have boot option set as UEFI/EFI. I then ran GRUB and Ubuntu worked.
    (problem: GRUB can't boot into Windows
    (problem 2: Windows updated and now GRUB can't find the partition)

I now can't turn off UEFI/EFI even looking at the same tutorial.

My question is: How to install? or How to turn off boot UEFI/EFI on my PC?

I have a EFI partition, could that cause a problem?.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from Linux and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates. Without the information in this script, answers will be based on (possibly incorrect) assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made it work :)

you will nead the latest ubuntu (i use [ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)) *choose the correct version for your computer*

In windows open windows disk management

1. make c partiton smaller (i cut 25 GB)
2. Boot USB/CD in EFI/UEFI
3. I chose install on the FREE space :P (it is good)

NOW HARD PART :D

1. you wil get new boot option in bios : ubuntu
2. **make this option first in list** (((importent))
3. BOOT USB/CD in EFI/UEFI
4. INSTAL Boot-Repair
5. do repair
6. now you have got windows 7 and ubuntu 2boot 10.

Answer (score 0):

> How to install?

just follow [these recommendations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Installing_Ubuntu_Quickly_and_Easily_via_Trial_and_Error).

> How to turn off boot UEFI/EFI on my PC?

some clues [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Set_up_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode).

> I have a EFI partition, could that cause a problem?.

No.

For more info, please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Comment: ACH :D i read it all. And make installation in 30 differents ways.

Comment: @Martin were u able to make it work? I'm facing the same problem and have tried 5 installations, none of them worked.